# MVC Data Store - WebORB, Sencha, Ext Js 4

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, weborb

I am trying with EXT JS 4, Sencha Touch 2.0 and WebORB.

What I am trying to build a store in MVC of Sencha Touch through Ext dynamically.
I have called the below javascript function as below in the  section in Index.html:

```
<script src="sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
                <script src="webORB.js"></script>
                <script>
                var dataFetched;
                var dataGet=function(){
        <!--  Class Name and URL are replaced in the original program-->
                this.proxy = webORB.bind("ClassName", "URL");
                    dataFetched=this.proxy.GetClassList(1301722);   
                //console.log(dataFetched);
            }
                </script>
                <script src="app.js">
</script>
```

The following is my *app.js*

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true

});
Ext.application({
    name: 'SBR',
    controllers: [
        'Main','Blog','Comments'
    ],
    views : [
    'Home','Blog', 'Comments'
],
    models : ['Comments'],
    stores: ['Comments'],
    launch: function(){
        dataGet();
        console.log(dataFetched);
        Ext.create('SBR.view.Viewport');
    }
});
```

The following is my Comment.js - Store

```
Ext.define('SBR.store.Comments',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',   
    config: {
        model: 'SBR.model.Comments',
        data: dataFetched
    }

});
```

The following is Comment.js - Model

```
Ext.define('SBR.model.Comments',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        config: {
            //fields: ['subject','body']
            fields: ['bookImageUrl','authorFirstName','authorLastName']
        }
    })
```

The following is the Comment.js - View

```
Ext.define('SBR.view.Comments',{
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'commentspage',
    config:{
        title: 'Comments',
        iconCls: 'star',
        //indexBar: true,
        store : 'Comments',
        itemTpl: '{authorLastName}',
        onItemDisclosure: function(item) {
            console.log('Disclose more info on' + " " + item.data.subject);
        }
    }
});
```

If I define the store with static Json Data it is working fine, but when I try to access it with WebORB it does not.

The console entries are done before it shows data to the console. Why it is not showing any data in the comment's view or my approach is entirely wrong for collecting and loading data through WebORB to the store?

Answer (score 0):

Oh Yes... I got it....

I just changed the following:

1. I transferred the function dataget() from index.html to Comments.js-Store and called the same function inside the config of the same file like:

data: dataGet()

Thats it...it worked..